# Boolean logic in Django template system

Tags: django, django-templates

If you set a context variable (eg. 'woot') as None or just leave it undefined....

> {% if woot %}   Yeah! {% endif %}

Does what you'd expect (nothing).  But if you do:

> {% if woot == True %}   Yeah! {% endif %}

It will print "Yeah!" even though woot is None / undefined.  That seems very non-intuitive.  Obviously, I can work around this... but I'd like to understand the root cause.  Any ideas why it happens....?

Proof:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

x = Template("{% if woot %}Yeah!{% endif %}")
y = Template("{% if woot == True %}Yeah!{% endif %}")

x.render( Context( {} ))  # => u''
y.render( Context( {} ))  # => u'Yeah!'

x.render( Context( {'woot':None} ))  # => u''
y.render( Context( {'woot':None} ))  # => u'Yeah!'
```

*This is on Django 1.4.3*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Django 1.5 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5-alpha-1/#minor-features)), the template engine interprets `True`, `False` and `None` as the corresponding Python objects, so `{% if woot == True %}` will evaluate to `False`.

In earlier versions of Django, neither the `woot` nor `True` variables exist in the template context. The expression `None == None` evaluates to `True`, so *Yeah!* is displayed

Comment: Thanks.  Perfectly reasonable explanation.  Yet another reason I look forward to upgrading to 1.5.